# mongodb driver has bugs during iteration? document contain invalid UTF-8?

Tags: mongodb

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.6
Build Info: {
    "version": "4.4.6",
    "gitVersion": "72e66213c2c3eab37d9358d5e78ad7f5c1d0d0d7",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "ubuntu2004",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

I had mongodb crash during indexing:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-09T15:02:31.139+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20649,   "ctx":"IndexBuildsCoordinatorMongod-0","msg":"Index build failed","attr":{"buildUUID":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"5ed4dd6b-420b-46e3-8611-3fba75d9739e"}},"namespace":"testdb.articles","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"cdf839b1-a9b4-4dfb-a500-c1f80f2dea2a"}},"error":{"code":28755,"codeName":"Location28755","errmsg":"text contains invalid UTF-8"}}}
```

I wonder how can I actually locate this document and remove it? I am using pymongo

Is there any log file related to the buildUUID can tell me what the id of the document is? Or maybe there is some mongo command can let me detect the invalid UTF-8?

#### strange bson decoding error

I use following code to try to detect the problem

```py
def check_doc(skip: int):
    it_cursor = col.find().skip(skip)
    count = 0
    while True:
        try:
            doc = it_cursor.next()
            print(f"{count}, {doc['_id']}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"i={count}, last doc {doc}", file=sys.stderr)
            raise e
        count += 1
```

Then I detect a problem after `'_id':ObjectId('60e7a4e2a3a21f66d1895c46')`

```
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/message.py", line 1615, in unpack_response
    return bson._decode_all_selective(
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bson/__init__.py", line 1089, in _decode_all_selective
    return decode_all(data, codec_options)
bson.errors.InvalidBSON: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

However, if I use following code I can actually get document and I cannot see anything abnormal there:

```
col.find({"_id":bson.ObjectId('60e7a4e2a3a21f66d1895c47')}).next()
```

Does this means the bug is actually in the driver and the document is actually ok?

I just found out change the skip value, the invalid utf8 error jumps around a lot. The documents are ok in some runs but reporting error in other runs. For example `check_doc(23447800)` and `check_doc(23447850)` both start to raise error at round 101, which cannot be true: if the document 23447901 really has problem then the second check_doc will raise error at round 51.  So I guess this is a driver bug.

I try to reproduce this in mongo shell, but I cannot, following command does not cause any problem:

```
db.articles.find().skip(23447800).forEach(function(doc){printjson(doc);})
```

Another funny finding, if I impose a limit() then the error is gone. So this error only happens in pymongo iteration without limit and the text indexing. `check_doc(23447800, 205)` won't raise any error.

```
def check_doc2(skip: int, limit: int):
    it_cursor = col.find().skip(skip).limit(limit)
    count = 0
    while True:
        try:
            doc = it_cursor.next()
            print(f"{count}, {doc['_id']}, {doc['pmid']}")
        except StopIteration:
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"i={count}, last doc {doc}", file=sys.stderr)
            raise e
        count += 1
```

Comment: It would be a field that's part of your text index?

Comment: I do not think so. It just randomly shows up now I do not even have any text index yet. I simply loop through all documents then the invalid utf8 error jumps around. I think this more looks like a serious driver bug

Comment: Could be a challenge, because unlike many other "old" applications, MongoDB uses only UTF-8 from the beginning, there are no legacy issue with old character sets.

Comment: more likely there are some undefined behaviour or memory problem in either driver or mongod. Because it always starting to have problem after iteration of 101. no matter where do you start after certain point.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit This actually surprised me. Because I checked our insert source code, we actually only support ASCII ISO646. SO it is unlikely to insert any non-UTF8 char at all. We never had this problem before till recently our number or records exceeds 20M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after dig into the code. I found out that pymongo read document in bulky way when iterate through the cursor. Thus the check_doc() is not a good way to locate the problematic documents. When yield the current cursor, pymongo continue to read the later documents and raise error if the next bulk read has problem. The better way is to use following function with exact match to retrieve documents starting from the point where check_doc() start to give out error.

```
def check_doc3(start_id, count: int):
    ret = []
    st = int(str(start_id), 16)
    for i in range(st, st+count):
        try:
            _id = bson.ObjectId("%x"%i)
            col.find({"_id": _id}).next()
        except StopIteration:
            break
        except Exception as e:
            ret.append(i)
            print(e)
    return ret
```